# how to do a list navigation into a node content

Tags: entities, navigation

I have a content type with some custom text fields. when the node displays I'd like to show it like this:

node-title

- field-1 (link)
- field-2 (link)
- field-3 (link)

field-1-content

field-2-content

field-3-content

this is for a new site, so I'd like to do that on Drupal 8 (with bootstrap theme).

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement you should go for twig to your content type:

> node--content-type.html.twig

In [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) render all the fields you would like to show in twig file.

For better understanding of twig file follow [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming).

Comment: thanks! but could you elaborate a little on how to do that? i'm new this kind of dynamic templates and specifically to twig templates

Comment: Copy node.html.twig as node--content-type.html.twig and print the elements as per your requirement.